How to switch sound and mic to USB-C handsfree?
I have a Samsung Galaxy A24 and a wired USB-C hands-free with earbuds and a microphone. How do I use it with the phone?
When I plug it into the USB-C socket on my Android phone, nothing happens. In contrast, when I plug in a 3mm jack (of another hands-free) into the phone's 3mm socket, the phone automatically switches to it.
As for a USB-C hands-free, is there a setting to tell the phone that it should now play the sound through the USB-C earbuds and use this microphone? The USB hands-free itself works perfectly with my Windows laptop.
